# NGINX Doesn't communicate with flask rest API. Docker

Tags: python, angular, docker, nginx, flask

NGINX Doesn't communicate with flask rest API. **When I hit localhost/api** 
If i hit localhost i get the message from the index.html but not json response when i hit /api

I want to use NGINX to serve my Angular 5 dist folder.

What is dist?

dist is the folder were I have my index.html, main.css, and all the others files that Angular 5 creates for me after I run ng build --prod

What is my problem?

- I want to have Angular 5 for the front-end
- I want my flask to be my rest api
- And I want nginx to serve all the static files (HTML, CSS, and javascript)

I want the user if is type in the URL (http://localhost) the NGINX to give him all the static files and let my SPA application to desite for the ROUTES Except for the API routes

If the user types (http://localhost/api)  I want the FLASK to take the control and give the user JSON response whatever I say the flask to response

My problem is when the user hits ## /api I get 404 page not found
WTF I have set inside nginx if is get /api to let the flask to take action
look:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}



http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  sendfile        on;
  #tcp_nopush     on;

  keepalive_timeout  65;

  gzip  on;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;


  # Configuration for the server
  server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index  index.html;
      expires -1;
      add_header Pragma "no-cache";
      add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
      try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
      proxy_pass  http://localhost:5000/;
    }

    # location /api {
    #   proxy_pass          http://flask_api:5000;
    #   proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    # }

    }



}
```

I have a docker-compose file that looks like this:

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

  nginx_demo:
    image: nginx:1.13.7-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx/Dockerfile
    volumes:
     - ./Client/dist:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - flask_api

  flask_api:
    # image: flask
    container_name: flask_api
    restart: always
    build: ./Server
    volumes:
      - ./Server:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
```

### this is inside Server/api.py

```
''' Docker + python 3.6.3 '''

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api')
def hello():
    return 'Hello Form Flask'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

### this is my logs after I run docker-compose up

```
Creating flask_api ...
Creating flask_api ... done
Creating nginx ...
Creating nginx ... done
Attaching to flask_api, nginx
flask_api     |  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
flask_api     |  * Restarting with stat
flask_api     |  * Debugger is active!
flask_api     |  * Debugger PIN: 718-970-762
nginx         | 172.20.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2017:14:16:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx         | 172.20.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2017:14:16:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx         | 172.20.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2017:14:16:56 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx         | 2017/12/10 14:16:59 [error] 5#5: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/api" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
nginx         | 172.20.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2017:14:16:59 +0000] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx         | 172.20.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2017:14:17:01 +0000] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx         | 2017/12/10 14:17:01 [error] 5#5: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/api" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
nginx         | 2017/12/10 14:17:02 [error] 5#5: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/api" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
nginx         | 172.20.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2017:14:17:02 +0000] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Comment: In the `docker-compose.yml` you are publishing the the wrong port. Also consider using `links` to specify the host for nginx. Take a look at it here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links

Comment: Thank you @ Ehsan in the docker documentation they don't say anything about NGINX and Flask .only flask and REDIS. What port should i use

Comment: You have mapped the ports from both containers to 80 on the host machine. Change the published port for `flask_api` to `"5000:5000"`, because that's where nginx is expecting to connect.

Comment: Also `proxy_pass  http://localhost:5000/;` in nginx config is wrong, bacause it is referring to the nginx container itself. You should specify `flask_api` in a `links` section for `nginx_demo` in your docker-compose file and then you can refer to the address of flask app with `flask_api`.

Comment: not is not working I gonna post all my code can you please take a look what is my problem give me 5 minutes please

Comment: Can you please look what I do wrong I make all you say this is the code exactly what i have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

### docker-compose.yml

```
# Run docker-compose up

version: '3'

services:
  nginx_demo:
    image: nginx:1.13.7-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Nginx/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./Client/dist:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - flask_api
    links:
      - flask_api

  flask_api:
    container_name: flask_api
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Server/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./Server:/usr/src/app
```

### Nginx/Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.13.7-alpine

# remove the old nginx.conf
RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Copy custom nginx config
COPY ./Nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./Client/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
```

### Server/Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

ADD ./Server /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "api.py"]
```

### Nginx/nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  sendfile    on;

  keepalive_timeout  65;

  gzip  on;

  # Configuration for the server
  server {

    listen 80;

    location /api {
      proxy_pass http://flask_api:5000;
    }

    location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index  index.html;
      expires -1;
      add_header Pragma "no-cache";
      add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
      try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Works perfectly :)

Comment: Sir, is there an article that guides you through the proper use of Nginx and docker using Python Flask?